# copy-paste short one dimensional dataframe to an empty column in other bigger dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, copy-paste

need to copy this vector/one dimensional dataframe (df1) to its respective column in different(and longer) dataframe (df2):
**df1**:

```
ID                  
44    
22      
66      
77
```

**df2:**

```
ID  c2  c3  c4   c5
nan   1   2   2   1
nan   1   3   2   3
nan   3   4   4   3
nan   4   5   6   5
nan   5   6   9   7
nan   1   3   1   5
```

desired df2 output after copy-pasting ID values:

**df2:**

```
ID  c2  c3  c4  c5
44   1   2   2   1
22   1   3   2   3
66   3   4   4   3
77   4   5   6   5
nan  5   6   9   7
nan  1   3   1   5
```

Thank you

Comment: Are the indices aligned? Have you tried `df2['ID'] = df1['ID']`?

Comment: Is it in order? So, 44 first, 22 second. And so on?

Answer (score 0):

```
df2.update(df['ID'].astype(str))
```

```
    ID      c2  c3  c4  c5
0   44      1   2   2   1
1   22      1   3   2   3
2   66      3   4   4   3
3   77      4   5   6   5
4   NaN     5   6   9   7
5   NaN     1   3   1   5
```